# Le groupe nominal complexe, une question de formes équivalentes

Tags: ellipse, groupe-nominal

On trouve la phrase suivante dans un article de [La Presse](https://www.lapresse.ca/techno/mobilite/201901/21/01-5211779-donnees-personnelles-lue-impose-une-amende-de-50-millions-deuros-a-google.php), parution canadienne.

- En même temps que sa plainte contre Google, la Quadrature du Net a déposé des plaintes de même type contre deux autres géants du net, Facebook et Amazon. Elles ne seront pas instruites directement par la Commission française, mais **par ses équivalents irlandais pour Facebook et luxembourgeois pour Amazon**, qui sont les autorités « chef de file » pour l'UE pour ces deux entreprises.

La forme sans ambigüité possible du syntagme en gras ci-dessus (forme 1) est « **mais par son équivalent irlandais pour Facebook et son équivalent Luxembourgeois pour Amazon** » (forme 2, forme de base) ; il est, semble t-il, évident qu'il ne s'agit que d'une commission pour l'Irlande et d'une seule aussi pour le Luxembourg, d'où la justification de la forme de base; à la lecture de la phrase initiale on est soumis à ce qui apparait être un bloc indépendant : **ses équivalents irlandais pour Facebook** ; l'impression est d'emblée que l'on parle de plusieurs équivalent pour Facebook et cette impression ne trouve une correction que difficilement lorsque la seconde partie est internalisée (luxembourgeois pour Amazon) ; il me semble que cette transformation du syntagme de base que l'on trouve dans la phrase initiale (forme 1) n'est pas d'une sorte permise, et que du moins elle relève d'un style très médiocre ; il me semble  que l'on ne peut pas sacrifier la souplesse de la lecture à cette moindre nécessité qu'est l'économie de mots.

La transformation de la forme de base en « **ses équivalents, irlandais pour Facebook et luxembourgeois pour Amazon** » (forme 3) n'entraine plus d'une façon flagrante le malaise de lecture auquel il est référé ci-dessus ; noter que le décodage comporte toujours un élément d'incertitude (plusieurs équivalents pour l'Irlande).

Une dernière transformation de la forme de base, « **ses équivalents, celui d'Irlande pour Facebook et celui du Luxembourg pour Amazon** » (forme 4) élimine toute incertitude et n'a que l'inconvénient de référer à ces deux commission par l'intermédiaire d'un pronom masculin, nécessairement masculin au vu de l'antécédent, mais la forme 1 n'est pas meilleure sous ce rapport-là.

Les questions suivantes se posent ;

1/ La syntaxe de la forme 1 est-elle correcte vu le contexte sémantique (une commission pour l'Irlande, une pour le Luxembourg) ?

2/ Si la syntaxe est correcte, ne doit-on pas incriminer le seul facteur d'évaluation de la phrase qui reste, c'est à dire le style, comme étant non satisfaisant et exiger une modification telle que celles apportées par les formes 3 et 4 ?

NB *autre formulation correcte*  Elles ne seront pas instruites directement par la Commission française, mais **par ses équivalents irlandais et luxembourgeois pour Facebook et Amazon respectivement**. (due à user **Aweuzegaga**)

Comment: Une autre façon de le dire aurait été : _Elles ne seront pas instruites directement par la Commission française, mais par ses équivalents irlandais et luxembourgeois pour Facebook et Amazon respectivement._

Comment: Il y a une question la dedans?  Chipoter sur les formes du francais bureaucratique est une occupation futile au mieux

Comment: @GeorgeM C'est justement du langage utilisé dans la bureaucratie, la loi et la science que l'on exige une précision mathématique et celle-ci reste néanmoins un « ingrédient » essentiel de tout le reste de la langue sérieuse.  (champ 1)

Comment: Ceci dit, il est évident que dans le cas présent il n'y a aucune spécificité bureaucratique qui soit en question ; pour vous aider à « see the wood for the trees » essayez « le pays était prisé pour ses parcs montagneux dans l'arrière pays et forestier dans le pays de plaine ». Ne vous trompez pas dans le nombre de parcs… N'hésitez pas non plus à pointer le chipotage, si vous pouvez le faire précisément. (fin)

Comment: Personnellement, je préfère la forme 3 (ou la 4) mais la première forme m'en bouge une sans faire bouger l'autre, pour être honnête.

Answer (score 2):

Premièrement, je crois que la question est parfaitement valide. On veut pouvoir croire que la langue peut exprimer des choses complexes sans ambiguïté.

Je m’excuse donc humblement de contourner un peu la question, si elle avait des vues plus générales. Je ne suis pas capable de fournir un autre exemple pour lequel l’ambiguïté persisterait, et me contente donc de montrer que ce cas particulier est parfaitement clair dans sa version originale. Citons-la pour mémoire :

> En même temps que sa plainte contre Google, la Quadrature du Net a déposé des plaintes de même type contre deux autres géants du net, Facebook et Amazon. Elles ne seront pas instruites directement par la Commission française, mais **par ses équivalents irlandais pour Facebook et luxembourgeois pour Amazon,** qui sont les autorités « chef de file » pour l'UE pour ces deux entreprises.

Repositionons l’emphase et simplifions un peu la phrase pour se concentrer sur ce qui semble accrocher :

> ...pas par la **Commission française**, mais par ses équivalents **irlandais** pour Facebook et **luxembourgeois** pour Amazon...

Nous parlons donc d’équivalents à la Commission française, qui est assez explicitement une institution de France, et qui désigne une entité unique, mise au singulier. On peut donc supposer sans trop se poser de questions que les équivalents mentionnés sont **eux aussi des entités uniques,** et le fait de les introduire par des **adjectifs liés à des états existants** indique assez bien qu’ils ont en leurs pays respectifs les mêmes genres de statut et fonctions que la Commission française en France. L’unicité et les pouvoirs de la première est garante de l’unicité et des pouvoirs de ceux qui suivent, puisqu’ils sont introduits par **ses équivalents.**

Je suis d’accord, par ailleurs, que deux adjectifs se terminant par un *« s »* même au singulier camouflent un peu les singuliers dans ce cas particulier, mais pas au point de ne pouvoir les identifier.

Le fait que l’introducteur ***par*** n’est pas mentionné à nouveau avant ***luxembourgeois*** rattache aussi clairement l’adjectif à ***équivalents***, justifiant sa marque du pluriel.

Si l’on avait plutôt plusieurs entités en charge de l’instruction, au Luxembourg disons, on verrait mieux quelque chose comme :

> En même temps que sa plainte contre Google, la Quadrature du Net a déposé des plaintes de même type contre deux autres géants du net, Facebook et Amazon. Elles ne seront pas instruites directement par la Commission française, mais **par son équivalent irlandais** pour Facebook et **par les commissions désignées par le gouvernement luxembourgeois** pour Amazon, qui sont les autorités « chef de file » pour l'UE pour ces deux entreprises.

N’étant pas versé en matière de droit, je ne peux par contre pas confirmer qu’une telle situation pourrait être envisageable dans la réalité... Mais je note les deux différences importantes introduites dans cette nouvelle version :

- **son équivalent** irlandais
- et **par** les commissions

Comment: Votre argument repose essentiellement sur « on peut donc **supposer** … eux aussi … uniques » ; je suis bien d'accord avec cette conclusion, c'est la meilleure supposition qui puisse être faite, celle qui très probablement sera vérifiée, et c'est celle que je fais initialement, mais ce n'est qu'une supposition.

Comment: @Fólkvangr S'ils sont **équivalents** à une entité unique, de l'importance de la Commission française, la conclusion la plus naturelle, celle qui ne requiert pas d'explications supplémentaires, est qu'ils sont aussi des entités uniques. Quelque chose comme «La reine d'Angleterre est ses équivalents hollandais et suédois» n’est pas pas élégant, mais indubitablement on ne s'attend pas à un doublon hollandais ou suédois. Si un quelconque autre pays est dirigé par l'Althing (disons), on dirait plutôt «La roi de Norvège et la plus haute autorité islandaise», en laissant de côté l'équivalence.

Comment: @LPH Je crois que la langue peut se permettre, en certains cas, d'économiser les mots, si la logique permet de reconstruire la situation sans ambiguïté. Vous avez, je crois, convenablement interprété d'entrée de jeu la valeur de l'affirmation, ce qui en un sens montre qu'elle est assez claire. D'autres interprétations sont-elles possibles? C'est certain! Sont-elles justes, cependant, et pourquoi le seraient-elles ou ne le seraient-elles pas? Je crois que l'analyse montre qu'elles seraient au mieux maladroites.

Comment: Somme toute vous considérez la formulation un à peu près acceptable, à prendre comme modèle ?

Comment: @LPH Je préfère la formulation originale à celles plus développées. Vous me permettrez cependant de ne pas prendre position sur l'établissement d'un modèle. Je me dis qu'à chacun ses manières et tournures, et que si on croit avoir une meilleure idée, qu'on la soumette à l'attention des gens. Si elle est vraiment avantageuse, les gens l'adopteront peut-être. Sinon, on le saura bien assez tôt...

Comment: @LPH En gros, je la trouve acceptable et claire. Mais claire ici ne veut pas dire qu'elle ne requiert qu'une attention partielle. Elle est complexe, pas forcément compliquée mais néanmoins élaborée. En saisir toutes les nuances et écarter les mauvaises interprétations qui sont juste là, presqu’affleurantes, demande une certaine attention.

Comment: Cette perception de l'existence d'un problème, même sans concevoir une solution, apporte un élément  positif et jointe à des remarques par d'autres lecteurs prouve que la recherche dans le sens de ma question n'est pas entièrement vaine.

Comment: J'aime bien la notion "que deux adjectifs se terminant par un «s» même au singulier camouflent un peu les singuliers dans ce cas particulier ... ." Dans le cas (hypothétique) où  les 2 adjectifs/pays ne se termineraient pas par "S" au singulier (belge et italien, par ex), est-ce que la présence (encore hypothétique) des 2 "S"(e.g., "par ses équivalents belgeS pour Facebook et italienS pour Amazon ...") serait, par contre, une indice  que les équivalents belges et italiens ne sont pas automatiquement des entités uniques? Thanks!

Comment: @PapaPoule Vraiment désolé pour la réponse en anglais. Je reformule dans la langue de Molière: Je crois que vous avez raison, ça indiquerait bien de multiples entités là où la Commission française serait une et une seule. Je souhaiterais néanmoins que tout ceci demeure dans le domaine de l'hypothéthique, là où vous l'avez mis d'entrée de jeu. Sinon, ça ne ferait que nuire à la capacité du français d'exprimer simplement la complexité, en offrant des cas avérés de possibilités d'interprétations multiples.

Answer (score 1):

En réponse, à vos questions:

1/ Oui, la syntaxe est parfaitement correcte.

2/ Non, il n'y a rien à incriminer, ni à exiger.

En français, il y a moult manières de dire la même chose. Considérant que la syntaxe est bonne, la perception de celle-ci apporte des nuances dans ses possibles interprétations.

*Sur le fond, je rejoins assez le commentaire de George M*